# Template matching for detecting multiple objects in image (+500 different categories)

Tags: python, computer-vision, multi-class, object-detection

I want to detect items from the inventory of a game. Detection is in real time, so I need decent performance (> 5 FPS). There are over 500 different items, but the item icons will not change so a classic template matching approach might work.

The problem is, I don't know what is the best way to do this. I have some background on DNNs but little background using classic computer vision algorithms. I'm testing with the `opencv` function `matchTemplate`. Should I do a for loop for the 500+ categories? In addition, there will be multiple items on the screen at every moment, and if I search the full image I will have to do a lot of template matching checks. Any recommendation?

Comment: This might help https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/07/15/video-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/

Comment: @MehmetSuzen sadly it doesn't. I know how to do training and inference with Deep Learning models, but I don't think Deep Learning is a good solution for my problem.